# Код не работает на api 16 а на 28 все работает как можно поправить?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
final String appPackageName = "com.viber.voip"; // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
                            try {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                            }
```

Comment: Это эмулятор? Возможно не установлено приложение Play Market, или вы его ни разу не запускали и не входили в аккаунт. И поскольку первый интент не срабатывает, то запускается второй, но маркет не поддерживает старый стоковый браузер. Хотя если в браузере открыть настройки и поставить галку "Полная версия" - то всё откроется.

Answer (score 0):

Код работает корректно, просто Google Play не поддерживает версию браузера, которая установлена на телефоне.